# Laravel horizon: multiple supervisord process; need seperation of concern

Tags: docker, laravel-5, amazon-ecs, horizontal-scaling, horizon

I have a laravel app setup on AWS ECS, I have dockerized my application and I am running the horizon supervisord in a separate container. All of the app containers are stateless and connect to one single redis/postgres server. Now since my application is in production I have two container instance running to divide the traffic load, And hence there are 2 supervisord queue workers spawning, And because of this the problem i am facing is that some of the jobs do not execute(atleast that is my analysis). Below is the horizon dashboard for better understanding.

[image]

You can see that the name [`supervisor-1`] of the process is the same and the queue they are listening are same as well. I feel this can be the reason of problem.

found this -> https://medium.com/@setkyarwalar/setting-up-multiple-horizon-workers-f75b233db521, which shows a setup of multiple horizon workers which are listening to different queues all together. That is not exactly my use case though.

I need to understand how i can solve the problem of concurrency happening, How could i have 2 separate workers listening to the same queue and still be able to execute all jobs smoothly?

Any help is appreciated in advance

Comment: Found -> https://github.com/laravel/horizon/issues/315, Might give a lead. Checking further

Comment: quoted in the above link `Horizon and Laravel Redis queue driver doesn't support Redis clustering`, Is this true. Cause AWS has redis clustering, because of which i had to change to original laravel connection configurations.

Comment: For now i scaled down to 1 server 1 worker mode. Until i am going to figure horizontal scaling, i will keep container sizes bigger to accommodate the traffic